# C program compiles but does not execute

Tags: c, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

I installed NetBeans for C successfully, but I don't know what is wrong because whenever I write any code it says "build successful" but it does not execute.
Nothing happens when I hit the run button, Netbeans just compiles the code but nothing is displayed on screen.

The Following is the simple code:

```
int main(void) {
    int a=0;
    printf("input any number");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And here is its compilation:

```
""/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/timekeeper/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ft'
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/ft.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/timekeeper/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ft'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d"
gcc -std=c99   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.c
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
gcc -std=c99    -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/ft build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o 
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/timekeeper/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ft'
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/timekeeper/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ft'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 34s)
""
```

What should i do?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to post your code as well.

Comment: the code is up there.

Comment: The console is probably closing as soon as it opens. Also, 34 seconds seems excessive for compile time on something so simple.

Comment: I just tried it in netbeans, and I got mine running well. In my case, actually after the build finished, Netbeans will open another output tab next to the building-output-tab. try to check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stdout` stream is line-buffered. That means whatever you `fwrite` or `printf`, etc. to `stdout` will not actually be written to your terminal until a newline character (`\n`) is encountered.

So your program has your string buffered, and is blocked on the `scanf`, waiting for your input from `stdin`. As soon as this happens, your console window is closing, and you never see the print.

To remedy this, either add a newline character at the end of your string:

```
printf("input any number:\n");        // Newline at end of string
```

or manually cause `stdout` to be flushed:

```
printf("input any number: ");
fflush(stdout);                       // Force stdout to be flushed to the console
```

Furthermore, I'm assuming that the `(total time: 34s)` figure includes the time the program was waiting for you to type something. You were incredibly patient, and after ~34 seconds, finally mashed something on the keyboard, after which the program ended and the console window closed.

Or, if Netbeans isn't opening a separate console window, this is all happening in one of those MDI panes of the Netbeans IDE.

Comment: So why am i encountering this strange problem with NetBeans? Have i not installed NetBeans correctly? If so, so can you suggest any webpage by which i can see and install it correctly.