# Cygwin, error for make "couldn't get proc lock" when compiling and running a C program

Tags: windows, makefile, cygwin, ncurses

## Problem

I have some half-year old c-programs I was working on and had hoped that I could continue working on them now. I did installed windows 10 (64-bit) right after that, so I thought could be a problem but the programs have run on windows 10 since then.

About 2 months ago, I could build with the make-file and run the executables but when I tried again today, it seems to me like the executables are not running. I have now also tried updating cygwin and (I think) all relevant packages.

I have googled if there are any important changes to cygwin but I didn't really find anything.

## Details

When I try running any program nothing happens for a long while at the `./executeables/helloworld.exe` line and then eventually producing the error:

```
$ make 1
gcc 1-helloworld.c -o ./executeables/helloworld.exe -lncurses
./executeables/helloworld.exe
      0 [sig] make 7332 get_proc_lock: Couldn't acquire sync_proc_subproc for(5, 1), last 7, Win32 error 0
   1324 [sig] make 7332 proc_subproc: couldn't get proc lock. what 5, val 1
```

After this, nothing happens and I cannot even stop the process with `ctrl+C` so I have to end "make.exe" (which oddly enough consists of 2 processes) with task manager. The terminal then says nothing more than

```
makefile:2: recipe for target '1' failed
make: *** [1] Error 1
```

So I'm guessing there is a problem with getting a mutex or a lock from windows for creating a process, but I have no clue why this would happen.

## Code

The example in this try uses this code for a hello world program, but it's the same for the more complex programs as well.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *message="Hello World";
    int row,col;
    int len = strlen(message);

    initscr();
    
    getmaxyx(stdscr, row, col);                  //screensize
    mvprintw(row/2, (col-len)/2, "%s", message); //center of screen
    getch();
    
    refresh();
    endwin();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Have anyone seen this problem before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Avast antivirus* was preventing the program from running correctly. Disabling it made everything run perfectly. I finally found the answer in this thread:

[Netbeans 8.1 IDE compiles and builds C programs but does not show their output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34230413/netbeans-8-1-ide-compiles-and-builds-c-programs-but-does-not-show-their-output)

**note:**
Since it is not marked as an answer to the question in that thread and because that question is not explicitly focusing the same error (although presents the same error), I will keep my question instead of marking it as a duplicate.

Thank you, Sheshadri Iyengar for providing the solution.

Comment: Thanks, that was really inobvious!

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem (configure hangs) too. I made an exception for the cygwin64-folder in avast, and was able to continue. I was able to put the process to sleep with ctrl-z, and using kill %n to kill the job.